# If $ f $ is increasing on $ (a, b) $ and for some $ x_0 \in (a, b) $, $ \lim_{x \to x} f(x) = L $, then $ f $ is continuous at $ x_0 $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, continuity

Let $ f $ be a monotonically increasing function on the interval $ (a, b) $ and let $ x_0 \in (a,b) $ such that $ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = L \in \mathbb{R} $. I need to prove that $ f \ $ is continuous at $ x_0 $. Can you verify my proof?

Suppose, to the contrary, that $ f(x_0) \lt L $. Therefore, $ L - f(x_0) > 0 $, which means that for $ \varepsilon = L - f(x_0) $, there exists a $ \delta > 0 $ such that for all $ x \in (a,b) $, if $ x \in (x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta) \setminus \{x_0\} $, then $ -\varepsilon \lt f(x) - L \lt \varepsilon $. Take $ x = \frac{x_0 + x_0 - \delta}{2} $, which is less than $ x_0 $ because $ \delta > 0 $ and is also in $ (x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta) \setminus \{x_0\} $. Therefore:

$$ -L + f(x_0) \lt f(x) - L \lt L - f(x_0) \Rightarrow  f(x_0) < f(x) $$

However, $ f $ is monotonically increasing, and $ x < x_0 $, which means  $ f(x) \lt f(x_0) $ - contradiction.

Suppose, to the contrary, that $ f(x_0) > L $. Therefore, $ f(x_0) - L \gt 0 $, which means that for $ \varepsilon = f(x_0) - L $, there exists a $ \delta > 0 $ such that for all $ x \in (a, b) $, if $ x \in (x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta) \setminus \{x_0\}, $ then $ -\varepsilon < f(x) - L < \varepsilon $. Take $ x = \frac{x_0 + x_0 + \delta}{2} $, which is greater than $ x_0 $ because $ \delta > 0 $, and is also in $ (x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta) \setminus \{x_0\} $. Therefore:

$$ L - f(x_0) < f(x) - L < f(x_0) - L \Rightarrow f(x) < f(x_0) $$.

However, $ f $ is monotnically increasing, and $ x_0 < x $, which means $ f(x_0) < f(x) $ - contradiction.

Therefore, $ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = L = f(x_0) $, which means $ f $ is continuous at $ x_0 $.

Comment: It's correct. ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: I suspect it's fine but you could shorten it somewhat, although then you might lost some clarity. So it's probably fine.

Answer (score 0):

The reasoning can be shortened substantially.

If $f$ is increasing then we have
$$L=\lim_{x\to x_0^-}\le f(x_0)\le \lim_{x\to x_0^+}=L$$
Therefore $L=f(x_0).$